# Is `gcloud dns record-sets import --delete-all-existing` transactional?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

When updating the contents of a zone using:

```
gcloud dns record-sets import RECORDS_FILE --zone=ZONE --delete-all-existing --zone-file-format
```

Is this operation atomic? i.e. if I have a record in RECORDS_FILE which already exists in the zone, will it continue to serve throughout, or will there be a blip where it's unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

Using `--delete-all-existing` flag in `gcloud dns record-sets import` will delete existing record-sets BEFORE importing the record-sets in the records-file.

If you noticed any blips please open a bug with reproduction steps on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) and we will investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't documented if import is transactional, but if you require that, you can use

[gcloud dns record-sets transaction](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dns/record-sets/transaction/)